# GA implemented through GTM showing incorrect bounce rate on SPA

Tags: google-analytics, heap-memory, single-page-application, google-tag-manager, segment

I implemented GA through GTM on [this website](https://beta.joybird.com/). To make sure the setup is correct, I also connected Heap & Segment (Segment sends data to a different GA property than the GA property GTM sends data to). All other events & tracking info is consistent (i.e. page views, custom event tracking, etc.) it's just bounce rate that seems off.

These are the key points of the issue:

- **Heap** shows a bounce rate below 40%
- GA implemented through **Segment** shows a bounce rate below 40%
- GA implemented through **GTM** shows almost exactly double the bounce rate as Heap & the GA implemented through Segment. This leads me to believe that I am doing something wrong in my GTM implementation of GA. In the GTM implementation of GA:

  - I am sending virtual page views from GTM to GA with `page`, `title`, `campaignSource`, `campaignMedium`, `campaignContent`, & `campaignName` fields. These are fired on a custom page view event (see screenshot [here](https://share.getcloudapp.com/nOumoXe7)). The number of page views is correct.
  - I tried sending the page view event on history change but it ended up bringing the site to a halt any time a query parameter was added (i.e. `?material=leather`)
- The website is a Single Page Application (written in React)
- 100% of public traffic is being sent from a Facebook campaign

I feel like I've gone through every blog and every post on this matter and still can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: At first sigth, the tracking does not seem completely identical for the two properties, however you talked about pageviews but the number of sessions is the same?

Comment: Good catch! The **number of sessions** in GA implemented through GTM is almost double that of GA through Segment & Heap (GA/GTM: 100k sessions, GA/Segment: 50k sessions, Heap: 50k sessions). Some other numbers that are inconsistent are **pages per session**: showing half as many pages per session in GA through Segment & Heap (GA/GTM: 2 pages per session, GA/Segment: 4 pages per session, Heap: 4 pages per session), and **average session duration** showing half as many pages per session in GA/GTM  (GA/GTM: 1 minute, GA/Segment: 2 minutes, GA/Heap: 2 minutes).